# Error while installing ruby version 2 for windows

Tags: ruby, command-line, installation

I am trying to install ruby version for my computer but I am getting a error while I pressed 1 in the command prompt.

Here is the screenshot:
[image: Screenshot of error I am getting while trying to install ruby]

Can someone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Which installer and which version?

Comment: I used this installer... https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/ and I installed Ruby 2.4.1-2 (x64).

Comment: So that requires MSYS as part of the installation, and the first error you're getting is that MSYS is not available. Maybe try installing that separately?

Comment: How can I install MSYS?